# Trying to add already existing method to String in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add 'startsWith' method to the String prototype. But the TypeScript compiler gives an error since it considers it to already exist. Naming it to something else would be ugly. How should I implement it correctly?

```
interface String
{
   startsWith(str: string): boolean;
}


if (!String.prototype.startsWith)
{
   String.prototype.startsWith = function (str: string) : boolean
   {
      return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
   };
}
```

#### Generated error:

Build: Cannot convert '(str: string) => boolean' to '{ (find: string, pos?: number, case_?: boolean): boolean; (find: string, case_?: boolean): boolean; (find: RegExp, pos?: number, case_?: boolean): boolean; (find: RegExp, case_?: boolean): boolean; (str: string): boolean; }'

Comment: That code works for me both in VS and [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20String%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20startsWith(str%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(!String.prototype.startsWith)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20String.prototype.startsWith%20%3D%20function%20(str%3A%20string)%20%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.indexOf(str)%20%3D%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D). Can you give more info to reproduce that error?

Comment: Ouch! Now I feel a bit stupid...  The colliding definitions came from Sugar.js since I imported sugar.d.ts and still had an older implementation for 'startsWith' in my code. Sorry for taking up your time, but you made me discover the error. =)

Comment: Great, always fell glad to help.

Comment: Yeah startsWith isn't ecma standard so you shouldn't get a conflict unless some other lib/def has it :)

Comment: @AdrianRosca you should delete the question